Changing system font on Google Pixel running Android 12
I have a Google Pixel 3a running Android 12. Once upon a time – around 2019 – it had a "Themes" feature:
 
 

Later it disappeared, maybe with a Play Services update.
Is the functionality still available under the hood? For example, can I still change the system font? (Without root access, as I couldn't find any way to root it without going through the official "unlock > wipe" sequence.)

Based on precursory research, looks like it's related to the Pixel Themes app, possibly been updated since Android 12. Links: Pixel Styles & Wallpapers on Pixel 3, Here’s how to download and use Google’s ‘Pixel Themes’ app on your device (2019). Please note that downgrading system apps may make the system unstable.
